# Markup.IStyle.Connector.Connect error on binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Good time.
I have a problem with data binding in WPF.
If i use binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Converter={StaticResource string_cutter_width}}"/>
```

in code below I have a `Markup.IStyle.Connector.Connect` error on some computers.
I can't understand why.
If you met such behavior or have some ideas about it. PLEASE SHARE.

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.status_col_header}" Width="1*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate.Resources>
                            <local:Localizer2 x:Key="Localizer2" />
                        </DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Expander Header="{Binding status.Text, Converter={StaticResource Localizer2}}" MouseEnter="Expander_MouseEnter" Tag="{Binding}">
                            <TreeView x:Name="GTree" ItemsSource="{Binding status.files}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ClipToBounds="False" IsHitTestVisible="true" Margin="1">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                    <local:string_cutter_width x:Key="string_cutter_width" />
                                                </StackPanel.Resources>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Converter={StaticResource string_cutter_width}}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Converter={StaticResource string_cutter_width}}"/>
                                                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>-->
                                            </StackPanel >
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                    <local:del_label_converter x:Key="del_label_converter" />
                                                </StackPanel.Resources>
                                                <!--<Image Source="Resources\delete_16.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" PreviewMouseUp="Image_MouseUp" Width="16" Height="16" Tag="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=start_btn, Converter={StaticResource del_label_converter} }"/>-->
                                                <Image Source="Resources\delete_16.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" PreviewMouseUp="Image_MouseUp" Width="16" Height="16" Tag="{Binding}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                            </TreeView>
                        </Expander>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Проверка подключения CamDrive" Click="MenuItem_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=camdrive_can_be_chk_manually}"/>
                <!--<MenuItem Header="Перезагрузка камеры" Click="RebootCamera_Click"/>-->
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
```

call stack:

```
в Camdrive.UpgradeTools.MainWindow.System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector.Connect(Int32 connectionId, Object target) в c:\Develop\Camdrive.Utils\Camdrive.UpgradeTools\Camdrive.UpgradeTools\MainWindow.xaml:строка 75
в System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
в System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
в System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
в System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren)
в System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
в System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
в System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.MeasureChild(UIElement child, Size constraint)
в System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.GenerateChild(IItemContainerGenerator generator, Size constraint, DataGridColumn column, Int32& childIndex, Size& childSize)
в System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.GenerateChildren(IItemContainerGenerator generator, Int32 startIndex, Int32 endIndex, Size constraint)
в System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.GenerateAndMeasureChildrenForRealizedColumns(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
в System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
в System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
в System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
в System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
в System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
в System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
в System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
в System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object  resizedCompositionTarget)
в System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
в MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr  wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
в MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam,  Boolean& handled)
в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object  args, Int32 numArgs)
в MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
в MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
в System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
в System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
в System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
в System.Windows.Application.Run()
в Camdrive.UpgradeTools.App.Main() в C:\Develop\Camdrive.Utils\Camdrive.UpgradeTools\Camdrive.UpgradeTools\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:строка 0
в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely it is because of nested templates:

CellTemplate -> **`DataTemplate`** -> ... -> TreeView -> TreeView.ItemTemplate -> **`DataTemplate`**

Quoting [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560631/net-framework-4-0-regression-in-wpf-exception-in-istyleconnector-connect-with-nested-itemscontrols-and-event-style-attributes-in-datatemplate):

> This bug requires a Template in a Template.  A good way to look at this problem “Templating is like parentheses, quoting parentheses” the Template XAML is not created but saved and run later. The bug is therefore: We have a problem with nested parentheses.

In the sample:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource Data}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" Width="30"
                                     Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded"
                                     Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The inner template is still `quoted` when the outer template is applied. Yet we still call IStyleConnector.Connect() for all the XAML (we don’t stop when we hit the `inner parentheses/quote`) and there is no TextBlock instance so we crash.

Weirdness happens with the repro because of optimized template sharing. For example if you remove the:

```
Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
```

The bug goes away because the TextBlock becomes `sharable` in the Template optimizer.

`WorkAround:`

The best work around is move the inner template to a resource.

Try move your `TreeView.ItemTemplate` in resource.

Comment: Is there a specific version of .NET that has this issue? Why do some machines exhibit this issue while others do not? Your workaround and suggestion worked like a charm!

Comment: @Mike G: What versions of frameworks on machines? This bug has moved from `.NET 3.5` to `.NET 4.0` version, exact same code under 3.5 has no problems. It is possible, in the 4.5 version it's fixed, as promised by Microsoft. In any case, as I think, should be avoided nesting templates and use through resources.